# How to set an IPN URL for PayPal Recurring Payments using ExpressCheckout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing, express-checkout

According to the PayPal documentation, it is not possible to have Instant Payment Notifications (`IPN`) for Recurring Payments when using ExpressCheckout.

Here is how I come up with that conclusion:

1. In the [`SetExpressCheckout` documenation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) for `NOTIFYURL` they say:

   > The notify URL applies only to `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`. This value is ignored when set in `SetExpressCheckout` or `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`.
2. I don't have a one-time payment with ExpressCheckout. I am just creating a recurring profile. So I am skipping the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` call like it is specified in the [`Recurring Payments integration guide`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/). Actually if I however do the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` call it would not be valid, because I have set the amount to `0`.
3. According to `1.` the `NOTIFYURL` (to be precise `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL`) would be ignored unless a `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` is called. However I have tried to set it in the `SetExpressCheckoutPayment` call.
4. Using the IPN simulator I am successfully receiving IPN notifications.
5. When successfully creating a new Recurring Payments profile using [`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) I am not receiving an IPN notification.
6. I did not find an API call related to the Recurring Payments which I can use to set a `NOTIFYURL`.

How can I set up an IPN URL for Recurring Payments using ExpressCheckout without an initial payment, `INITAMT` or other requiring `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`?

Comment: Have you tried to use initial payment and set it to 0?

Comment: @jayarjo I haven't. However I don't think this would work. It is very unlikely PayPal would allow a zero amount for a transaction. Even if they do, it would look strange in the bank statements of the customer. However this is a hack. I really wanted the PayPal API to support it natively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the IPN URL in your PayPal account, under your profile.

Comment: I wanted to have a different IPN for every different profile. Is setting it through the API not possible? Thanks!

Comment: Not with recurring payments.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad and what is PayPals suggested solution for multiple projects? Do I have to use separate PayPal account for each of them? Or do I have to create a centralized IPN Call Center and then sort out incoming notifications by project?..

Comment: it is shameless answer

Comment: How does one support a test environment if the IPN address can only be defined from the PayPal account?

Comment: not get any IPN response when my recurring success after a cycle .

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "&NOTIFYURL=yoursite.com/ipnhandle" to your NVP string, if you want to set different IPN urls for your each transaction.

Comment: If you read the PayPal documentation and my question more thoroughly you will know this is not possible with recurring payments.

Comment: If you are using Express Checkout you can do this.

Comment: I am using ExpressCheckout, but I am not using `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API operation. Please read my question again. I know how and where to use `NOTIFYURL`. The problem is that PayPal does not support it for my use case. You could see the comments under the accepted answer for more details.

Comment: If this is not working in your case, then IPN url set in your paypal account will send you notification every time..and you can filter the notification on the basis of transaction type (txn_type).

Comment: Thanks! This is very similar to what I did and what the accepted answer is about. I really hope PayPal extend their API and support this in the future.